# Creating network in ArcMap from an RGB image to find optimal path between locations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network, route

I am hoping to find optimal routes from an Origin (car park) to destinations (Library, Blocks, Rec Center).

I have an RGB ortho-mosiac image taken from an UAV that I want to digitize paths, car parks, and infrastructure, and then find an optimal route from one to another.

How would I go about making sure the polygons and lines can be used to distinguish which path might be the best to choose from?

And therefore adding stops etc. using network analysis toolbar.

Comment: Hey thanks, only just got to revisit this. Have had a bit more success thanks to the sharing vertices at each intersection. Have now got all but one destination and one origin connected to the network and was able to do an OD Cost path matrix and Closest facility solve to find optimal paths using time for measure.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need polygons, and in fact points for your origins and destinations would work better. You can have a point represent a building or parking lot, but it sounds like you're working at a pedestrian scale in which case it might be better to have points for specific building entrances or other such destinations.

The most important thing with your lines to make them useable as a network involves snapping. Be sure all lines are connected and snapped to each other. Furthermore, make sure that where two lines meet, if that is supposed to be an intersection, *both* have a shared vertex there. If they are not supposed to meet (for example a second floor connecting walkway crosses between buildings over a path outside/underneath) they should *not* have a shared vertex. Ideally, lines should be broken into separate lines at any intersection (four way intersection, four lines not two crossing).

From there it depends on your analysis and definition of 'optimal'. The lines will by default have the property of length, so you can do shortest path analysis. For time, you need some attribute of travel time for that edge, which you could create by dividing the length by a speed factor. Beyond that you're looking at other network edge attributes - maybe it's steep and has a cost penalty for that, or maybe you have a rating system for pleasantness to walk that factors into how favorable a route is.

I would suggest running through exercises 1-3 and 12 of the [Network Analyst tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_the_ArcGIS_Network_Analyst_extension_tutorial/00470000005r000000/) to get a feel for how things work.